# Rails _id sometimes not added to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class:

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Airport'
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Airport'
  belongs_to :key_transfer_country, class_name: 'Country'
end
```

with the corresponding entry in `schema.rb` of

```
create_table "routes", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "origin_id"
  t.integer  "destination_id"
  t.integer  "key_transfer_country_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

My `Airport` model includes:

```
has_many :from_routes, class_name: 'Route', foreign_key: 'destination_id'
has_many :to_routes, class_name: 'Route', foreign_key: 'origin_id'
```

and my `Country` model includes:

```
has_many :transfers, class_name: 'Route', foreign_key: 'key_transfer_country_id'
```

My problem comes when I try to create a route. Having set up `origin`, `destination` and `transfer` (which can be nil), I have:

```
route = Route.find_or_create_by(
  origin: origin,
  destination: destination,
  key_transfer_country: transfer
)
```

but I get an SQL error

```
no such column: routes.key_transfer_country: SELECT  "routes".* FROM "routes"  WHERE "routes"."origin_id" = 6658 AND "routes"."destination_id" = 8025 AND "routes"."key_transfer_country" IS NULL LIMIT 1 (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

So for some reason, Rails has appended `_id` to `origin` and `destination` (as I expected), but, for some reason I don't understand, it *hasn't* appended it to `key_transfer_country`, so the `SELECT` is failing.

Can anybody help me work out why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `key_transfer_country: <your_country_object>` ?

Comment: `transfer` *is* a Country object (or nil, which might be part of the problem because a nullable column shouldn't be part of a key)

Answer (score 0):

try to add the **foreign_key** to your relationship :key_transfer_country, like this

```
class Route < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Airport'
    belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Airport'
    belongs_to :key_transfer_country, class_name: 'Country', foreign_key: 'key_transfer_country_id'
end
```

This is because the name of the foreign key can not be assumed for some reason by the length of the field name. Let's try.

Sorry for my english